# Блокируется iFrame на любом сайте

Tags: javascript, iframe, виджет

Создал простую страничку: http://time.graphics/embed?v=1&id=4

Теперь хочу создать виджет, чтобы можно было встроить на любой сайт:

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" 
        src="" http://time.graphics/embed?v=1&id=4
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Но не работает. На CodePen тоже не работает:

https://codepen.io/jenkaman/pen/MoQzNo

Как быть? В чем может быть проблема? Как правильно создать виджет? Спасибо.

Comment: `502 Bad Gateway`

Comment: Напрямую открывает.

Comment: Открывайте в браузере консоль и инспектор сети и смотрите, что вам там интересного пишут ;)

Comment: Смотрел и ничего не увидел.

Comment: если загружаемый в iframe сайт находится не в одном домене с основной страницей, то скорее всего будет ошибка доступа к данным при попытке обратиться к ним

Comment: Что насчет youtube, adsense, vimeo да полно сайтов, которые используют iframe?

Comment: Нет ни каких проблем с отображением этого iframe на локалхосте.

Comment: У меня тоже отображается iframe на 127.0.0.1

Comment: Пишите разработчику сервиса, возможно у них глюк с доступом.

Comment: на sites.google.com такая же фигня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если внимательно посмотреть в консоль, то можно увидеть, что фрейм пытается сделать https запрос, хоть у него в src и прописан http протокол.
Попробуйте запустить его на http сайте (коими stackoverflow, codepen не являются), и вы увидите разницу.

Одно из решений [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Т.е. мне надо сделать https доступ к странице? Покупать ssl и всё такое..

Comment: Если вы имеете доступ к time.graphics/embed?v=1&id=4, то просто поднять на нём https. Если не имеете, то поднять прокси-сервис, который будет принимать на вход http сайты и выдавать их содержимое в https. Сертификаты можно получить бесплатно, почитайте про letsencrypt.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как сделать прокси-сервер?

Comment: letsencrypt – попробую эту штуку. отпишусь)

Comment: Спасибо. Перешел на https и всё заработало!

Comment: Отлично! Не забывайте вовремя продлевать сертификат.